# sending parameters to controller via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, yii

I want to do this:

I have 2 grids. I want to select **idideya** (from first grid) and **idperson** (from second grid) and send them to the **actionGonder()**. With this action data'll be **insert** to table.

The **success** 'section' of ajax function works fine (it correctly alerts **$perid** and **ideaid** every time). But the data isn't sends to the controller.

Pleaseee help me guys. I need help. Thanks.

Best regards.

> **view file**

```
<?php
    $this->widget('yiiwheels.widgets.grid.WhGridView', [
        'id' => 'layiheler-c',
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'filter' => $filtersForm,
        'ajaxUpdate'=>true,
        'responsiveTable' => true,
        'fixedHeader' => true,
        'headerOffset' => 40,
        'type' => 'striped bordered',
        'columns' => [
            [
                'name' => 'idideya',
                'headerHtmlOptions'=>['width'=>120],
                'header' => '#'
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'ideyaad',
                'headerHtmlOptions'=>['width'=>120],
                'header' => 'İdeya adı'
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'tarix',
                'headerHtmlOptions'=>['width'=>120],
                'header' => 'Təqdim olunma tarixi'
            ],
        ],
    ]);
?>

<button id="lrl" style="position: fixed">daxil et</button>
<br><br>

<?php
    $this->widget('yiiwheels.widgets.grid.WhGridView', [
        'id' => 'ekspertler-c',
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider2,
        'filter' => $filtersForm2,
        'ajaxUpdate' => true,
        'responsiveTable' => true,
        'fixedHeader' => true,
        'headerOffset' => 40,
        'type' => 'striped bordered',
        'columns' => [
            [
                'name' => 'idperson',
                'headerHtmlOptions'=>['width'=>120],
                'header' => '#'
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'adi',
                'headerHtmlOptions'=>['width'=>120],
                'header' => 'Ad'
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'familya',
                'headerHtmlOptions'=>['width'=>120],
                'header' => 'Soyad'
            ],
        ],
    ]);
?>

<button id="eks" style="position: fixed;left: 69%;top: 11%;">daxil et</button>

<div id="zirrama">
    <input type="text" readonly id="idea_text" />
    <input type="text" readonly id="person_text" />
</div>

<script>
$siraI;
$siraP;

$("#lrl").click(function (){
    $("#layiheler-c tr.selected").each(function () {
        $setir = $(this).find('td');
        if($setir.length != 0) {
            $hazirki = $setir.eq(1).text();
            $siraI = $setir.eq(0).text();
            //  alert($toplam);
            //  alert($mircalal);
            // alert('seçilmiş ideya adı: ' + $hazirki);
            $("#idea_text").val($hazirki).before("<input type='text' style='display: none;' id='idea_text' />");
        }
    });
});

$("#eks").click(function (){
    $("#ekspertler-c tr.selected").each(function () {
        $setir = $(this).find('td');
        if($setir.length != 0) {
            $hazirki = $setir.eq(1).text();
            $siraP = $setir.eq(0).text();
            // alert($siraP);
            // alert('seçilmiş ekspert adı: ' + $hazirki);
            $("#person_text").val($hazirki).before("<input type='text' style='float: right; display: none' id='person_text' />");
        }
    });
});

function updatefunc(){
    $perid  = $siraP;
    $ideaid = $siraI;
    //alert($perid + " " + " " + $ideaid);
    // alert(perid);
    $.ajax({
        URL: "gonder/perid=.'$perid'./ideaid=.'$ideaid'",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            'perid': $perid,
            'ideaid': $ideaid
        },
        success:function(data){
            alert ($perid + " " + " " + $ideaid); /*  this line works fine. it alerts which idea and person I selected.  */
        },
   });
}
</script>

<?php  echo CHtml::submitButton('gonder', array('onclick'=>'updatefunc();')); ?>
<?php /* echo CHtml::button('gonder', array('submit' => array('onclick'=>'updatefunc();'))); */ ?>
```

> **controller file**

```
public function actionGonder ()
{
    // die();
    echo "fsdfsdfsdfwtgikkyurtretgyuikuytryhjuhytryhk6ujkjyttyuj";
    if (isset($_POST['perid']) && isset($_POST['ideaid'])){
        $quer = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                ->insert ('mqrup', array(
                    'idperson'=> $perid,
                    'idideya'=>$ideaid ));
    // var_dump($quer);
    }
    // die();

    $this->redirect(array('umumi'));
}
```

Comment: why are you setting a funky querystring AND sending a data object? the data object is all that you need? and its properly alerting them because you declare those variables above the scope of the AJAX call ... its not alerting response data, its alerting the variables you define.

Comment: okay. I understand. but how to send data to controller?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
function updatefunc(){
$perid  = $siraP;
$ideaid = $siraI;
$.ajax({
    Url: <?php echo Yii::app()-     createUrl("controllerName/  gonder"),
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        'perid': $perid,
        'ideaid': $ideaid
    },
    success:function(data){
        alert (data);
     },
 });
}
```